# Get all ips in PCAP file

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I have a set of PCAP files and I need to retrieve all the ips. I found [this link](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/4827/determining-unique-mac-and-ip-addresses-in-a-pcap) and have currently been using this command.

```
tshark_path + " -r " + infile + " -T fields -e ip.dst | sort | uniq
```

The problem is this seems to be very slow and also occasionally returns something that looks like this: `128.219.232.12,10.78.0.131`. My question is if there is a better way to do this that will run quicker and be more accurate.

Also noteworthy, my code is in python.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [TShark Statistics](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):

```
tshark -r test.pcapng -q -z ip_hosts,tree
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Command prompt and go to `tshark` directory, for example:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Wireshark

tshark -nr input.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -E separator=, > ouput.csv
```

Here you have to provide `input.pcap` file with directory and you will get output in CSV format.